# How to initialize ShiftRegister primitive in Chisel

Tags: chisel

We are using ShiftRegister in Chisel 2 to implement a delay.  But it's not clear how to force it to initialize to a value of our choosing, such as forcing it to zero (NOT random).  How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not much with Chisel 2, but I believe [this ShiftRegister.apply](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel/blob/217cfbb10d5578a4b14a262ed662ba4f341b032d/src/main/scala/ChiselUtil.scala#L190) method should work.

In Chisel 3, there is an open PR to add this functionality. Without this PR, it is still possible as follows:

```
val shiftIn = Wire(UInt(32.W))
val shiftReg = ShiftRegister(Mux(reset, RESET_VALUE, shiftIn), n)
```

Just connect to `shiftIn` to input to the shiftReg.

Comment: The suggested solution can work given that the 'reset' signal is guaranteed to be active for at least 'n' cycles, which is not always guaranteed.  Will look into the shift register apply method.